# How to delete a Audience Manager Contact in code within Tridion 2011?

Tags: contacts, tridion

I'm using Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact and I can't find any method of deleting a Contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option in the Content Delivery API.

You can only delete Contacts on the Content Manager side. 
Use Tridion.AudienceManagement.API.Contact.Delete() to delete your Contacts.

Comment: Excellent. I was not aware of those Libraries and found them in the Tridion bin folder.  
  
Tridion.AudienceManagement.API.Contact contact = new Tridion.AudienceManagement.API.Contact(contactUri);    
contact.Delete();

Comment: And as an aside, this doesn't need to be done on thee cms machine. I did it from the CDA without any trouble, as long as the configs are ok in the binary folder.

Comment: Right, but in that case your CDA is acting like a CMS machine. The point is that you cannot do it using the CD API :)

Comment: Ah, yes. Well I was a little premature in saying that it worked. It actually doesn't..
If I can't do it using the CD API what alternatives do I have to delete a user?

Comment: Why can't you delete it on the CM server?

Comment: Its a user driven deletion, only happening on the CDA via the website.

Comment: Right, but that's just how it is initialized. You could, for instance, add a certain Keyword to Contacts that are supposed to be deleted and then clean them up regularly on the CM side. Or depending on your use for the Unsubscribe status, you could use that as the indicator.

Comment: Yeah, thats the suggestion I got, add a field to Audience Manager then run a scheduled task to delete it. My spider sense is urging me not to do it, but if its the only way.
I wondered whetehr adding a simple WCF service to the CMS would work also, and whether the restriction is based on the existance of licences on the server.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, of course, but I wouldn't personally open my firewall to allow deletion of Contacts from outside.

You don't have to add a field, you could create a specific Address Book which isn't synchronized anywhere. Then change the Contacts to be in that Address Book. That would - upon synchronization - remove them from the website and then allow you to delete the Contacts at your leisure.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Tridion you are using?

In 2011 SP1, there is new API namespace for Contact. AFAIK, It is possible in 2011 on wards but not on 2009 (read-only API ?).

Namespace:  Tridion.AudienceManagement.API. Below is the sample from API Docs

```
TcmUri uri = new TcmUri(3, 456, TcmItemTypes.Contact);
Contact contact = new Contact(uri);
contact.Delete();
```

Comment: There's no read-only API for Audience Manager. The same thing was possible in 2009; but Neil is asking about deleting them on the CD side.

Answer (score 1):

Removing users may only be possible on the Content Manager API. Or at least the API docs for the Content Manager mention a Contact.Delete method, while that isn't mentioned in the API docs for the Content Delivery API.

Comment: Ah.. I read the question now clearly.. Thanks Frank for the clarification. Yes, you are right. I do not see any API method to delete contact from ContentDelviery side.